# How to inline assembly in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly, inline-assembly

I'm trying to inject some assembly into an aplication but i'm getting errors on this line:
Here's the complete code

```
#define _TOJUMP 0xCDFA43 

BYTE bak_InitDamageBuff[6];

void unHook(BYTE* from, BYTE* backup, size_t size) {
    DWORD protect;
    VirtualProtect(from, size, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &protect);
    memcpy(from, backup, size);
    VirtualProtect(from, size, protect, &protect);
}

void Hook(BYTE* from, void* to, BYTE* backup, size_t size) {
    DWORD protect;
    VirtualProtect(from, size, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &protect);
    memcpy(backup, from, size);
    DWORD diff = ((DWORD)to - (DWORD)from) - size;
    memset(from, 0x90, size);
    *(BYTE*)from = 0xE9;
    *(DWORD*)((DWORD)from + 1) = diff;
    VirtualProtect(from, size, protect, &protect);
}

DWORD return_address = _TOJUMP + 0x6;
static __declspec(naked) void NewInitDamageBuff() {
    _asm {
        mov [edx + 0x29D0], 0x‭0F4240‬;    <-------------
        jmp return_address;
    }
}

void Main_thread() {
    while (1) {
        Hook((PBYTE)_TOJUMP, &NewInitDamageBuff, bak_InitDamageBuff, 6);
    }
}
```

What is wrong whith it?

The compiler is Visual Studio

I'm using it in portuguese, but ill try to translate the errors

-incorrect sufix on the number

-integer litarals must have at least one number

- something bad token

Comment: ambiguous operand-size, you need to tell the compiler if you want `dword ptr`, `word ptr`, or what.  This is probably what the error message tells you, but you left that out so this isn't a [mcve].

Comment: For starters every `call` is expected to meet a `ret`, and there is no telling if it's the case with this function (if you can even call this a function), it's unclear what you are doing, is this an attempt at hooking? Also do you even know the state of `edx` at the time the `call` is made? You seem to be pretty confident it's a valid memory address but how did you reach that conclusion?

Comment: *i'm getting errors* Then why aren't they included in your post? We can't see your screen from where we are, but you can. There's no reason for you to not include those errors in your post. Please [edit] to do so. While you're at it, you can add a tag for the compiler you're using as well.

Comment: @Havenard: A function can end with a `jmp` tailcall instead of a `ret`.  That's perfectly normal.  But yeah, good point that it shouldn't be called `return_address`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Now he posted more code, it's starting to make sense.

Comment: I suspect `mov dword ptr [edx + 0x29D0], 0x‭0F4240‬;` should compile, no warranties on it working though. There is no telling if jumping to `return_address` will produce a segmentation fault, and whatever was the original code in that 6 byte space is no longer being executed.

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_TOJUMP`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don’t use them in your code.

Comment: Doesn't masm use `40000000H` for hex numbers rather than `0x40000000`?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: MSVC inline asm allows C-style `0xdeadbeef` hex numbers, unlike MASM, last I checked.

Comment: Still not a [mcve].  https://godbolt.org/z/J917P7 won't compile because you didn't include any headers that define those types.  I tried to put it on Godbolt to see the error in English.  (But unfortunately it seems Godbolt doesn't have `<Windows.h>`.)

Comment: I don;t know if this is realated to portuguese version or not but there seem to be special characters in the line `mov [edx + 0x29D0], 0x0F4240‬` The `x` in `0x0F4240;` seems to be some other special character and there seems to be a special character before the `;`. I'd retype the entire line from scratch. Did you copy and paste this from another website or are you doing this on MacOS?

Comment: @MichaelPetch: heh, funny that we both came back to this question at the same time, hours after the edit to make it a non-minimal mostly-CVE.  The `x` is a plain ASCII `x`, according to my copy/paste hexdump, but it's followed by something funky.  I didn't look it up in a unicode table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some non-ASCII characters inside your `0x‭0F4240‬`; that's what MSVC is choking on.

---

MSVC inline asm does accept numberic literals in `0xDEADBEEF` C-style hex format (unlike MASM), so your asm looks like it should compile / assemble.  (Whether it's useful or not is another matter.)

The error messages are:

```
<source>(9): error C2059: syntax error: 'bad suffix on number'
<source>(9): error C2153: integer literals must have at least one digit
<source>(9): error C3872: '0xac': this character is not allowed in an identifier
<source>(9): error C2400: inline assembler syntax error in 'second operand'; found 'bad token'
```

I put your function on [the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'typedef+unsigned+long+DWORD%3B%0A%23define+_TOJUMP+0xCDFA43%0A%0A%0ADWORD+return_address+%3D+_TOJUMP+%2B+0x6%3B%0A%0Astatic+__declspec(naked)+void+NewInitDamageBuff()+%7B%0A++++_asm+%7B%0A++++++++mov+%5Bedx+%2B+0x29D0%5D,+0x%E2%80%AD0F4240%E2%80%AC%3B+++//+original%0A++++++++mov+%5Bedx+%2B+0x29D0%5D,+0x0F4240%3B+++//+retyped+compiles+fine+if+you+comment+out+the+original%0A++++++++jmp+return_address%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:51.99203187250996,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cl19_32,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O2',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86+MSVC+19+2017+RTW+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:48.007968127490045,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86+MSVC+19+2017+RTW',t:'0')),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:48.007968127490045,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',m:100,n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) to get the actual error messages, with a typedef for `DWORD` because Godbolt doesn't have a Windows.h to define it.

```
typedef unsigned long DWORD;
#define _TOJUMP 0xCDFA43

DWORD return_address = _TOJUMP + 0x6;
static __declspec(naked) void NewInitDamageBuff() {
    _asm {
        mov [edx + 0x29D0], 0x‭0F4240‬;   // original
        mov [edx + 0x29D0], 0x0F4240;   // retyped compiles fine if you comment out the original
        jmp return_address;
    }
}
```

Those error messages made me think there was a non-ASCII character in there it was choking on, and copy/paste into `hexdump -C` on my Linux desktop confirms it:

```
00000000  6d 6f 76 20 5b 65 64 78  20 2b 20 30 78 32 39 44  |mov [edx + 0x29D|
00000010  30 5d 2c 20 30 78 e2 80  ad 30 46 34 32 34 30 e2  |0], 0x...0F4240.|
00000020  80 ac 3b 0a                                       |..;.|
```

(`.` in the ASCII side of the output means a non-printable byte).

So right after the `0x` in the source operand of `mov`, there's a `80 ad 30` 3-byte UTF-8 sequence which apparently doesn't print as anything.

Comment: Came to this conclusion a few mins ago in the comments. How they got there I don't know.There is another such character before the `;`